# how to shows options when create class and inheritance from Gtk.ComboBox

Tags: python, combobox, gtk, gtk3

I made class named `Combo` and inheritance from `Gtk.ComboBox` in `GtkClass.py`:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Combo(Gtk.ComboBox):

    def __init__(self,opt):
        Gtk.ComboBox.__init__(self)
        self.options = opt
        self.set()

    def set(self):
        self.id_kitchen_list = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        for item in self.options:
            self.id_kitchen_list.append([item])

        self.id_kit_combobox = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model(self.id_kitchen_list)
        renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.id_kit_combobox.pack_start(renderer_text, True)
        self.id_kit_combobox.add_attribute(renderer_text, "text", 0)
        return self.id_kit_combobox
```

when I use this class in my `main.py` file:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

from GtkClass import Combo
class Assistant(Gtk.Assistant):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Assistant.__init__(self)
        self.set_title("Assistant")
        self.set_default_size(600, -1)

        box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.append_page(box)
        self.set_page_type(box, Gtk.AssistantPageType.INTRO)
        self.set_page_title(box, "Page 1: Kitchen")

        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        grid.set_row_spacing(10)
        grid.set_column_spacing(10)

        self.id_kit_combobox = Combo(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])
        grid.attach(self.id_kit_combobox, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        box.pack_start(grid, True, True, 0)
        self.set_page_complete(box, True)

assistant = Assistant()
assistant.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

`ComboBox` creates but shows no options when I click on it!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: `class inheritance` from `Gtk.ComboBox`

First, i want to show what is wrong with your implementation.

```
class Combo(Gtk.ComboBox):

    def __init__(self,opt):
```

1. Here you `__init__` the `inherieted` `Gtk.ComboBox`, but you didn't pass your `model=`. Therefore you get a `ComboBox` with a default model.

   ```
       Gtk.ComboBox.__init__(self)
       ...
   ```
2. Here, you instantiate the `ListStore` you want to use, but you don't `.set...` this `ListStore` to the allready instantiated `self` object which is of type `Gtk.ComboBox`.
   Therefore the appended options, never shows up.

   ```
   def set(self):
       self.id_kitchen_list = Gtk.ListStore(str)
       for item in self.options:
           self.id_kitchen_list.append([item])
   ```
3. Here, you instantiate a **new** object of type `Gtk.ComboBox` which  leads to `ComboBox` in `ComboBox`. This inner `ComboBox` will never show up.

   ```
       self.id_kit_combobox = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model(self.id_kitchen_list)
       ...
   ```
4. Here, you return a object which is never used from the calling `self.set()`.

   ```
       return self.id_kit_combobox
   ```

---

> **Solution**:

```
class Combo(Gtk.ComboBox):
    def __init__(self, opt):
        self.id_kitchen_list = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        Gtk.ComboBox.__init__(self, model=self.id_kitchen_list)

        for item in opt:
            self.id_kitchen_list.append([item])

        renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.pack_start(renderer_text, True)
        self.add_attribute(renderer_text, "text", 0)
```